# Regex for Encoded HTML

Tags: html, regex, validation, sanitization, html-encode

I'd like to create a regex that will match an opening `<a>` tag containing an href attribute only:

```
<a href="doesntmatter.com">
```

It should match the above, but not match when other attributes are added:

```
<a href="doesntmatter.com" onmouseover="alert('Do something evil with Javascript')">
```

Normally that would be pretty easy, but the HTML is encoded. So encoding both of the above, I need the regex to match this:

```
&#60;a href&#61;&#34;doesntmatter.com&#34; &#62;
```

But not match this:

```
&#60;a href&#61;&#34;doesntmatter.com&#34; onmouseover&#61;&#34;alert&#40;&#39;do something evil with javascript.&#39;&#41;&#34; &#62;
```

Assume all encoded HTML is "valid" (no weird malformed XSS trickery) and assume that we don't need to follow any HTML sanitization best practices. I just need the simplest regex that will match A) above but not B).

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the HTML encoded? And are it always the decimal character references?

Comment: We allow users to submit HTML via comments, so we encode everything using AntiXSS (which returns decimal char references) and then selectively decode the safe stuff using a whitelist-based approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how matching one is different from the other? You're just looking for exactly what you just wrote, making the portion that is `doesntmatter.com` the part you capture. I guess matching for anything until `&#34;` (not `&quot;`?) can present a problem, but you do it like this in regex:

> `(?:(?!&#34;).)*`

It essentially means:

- Match the following group 0 or more times

  - Fail match if the following string is `"&#34;"`
  - Match any character (except new line unless DOTALL is specified)

The complete regular expression would be:

```
/&#60;a href&#61;&#34;(?>(?:[^&]+|(?!&#34;).)*)&#34;&#62;/s
```

This is more efficient than using a non-greedy expression.

Credit to Daniel Vandersluis for reminding me of [the atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)! It fits nicely here for the sake of optimization (this pattern can never match if it has to backtrack.)

I also threw in an additional `[^&]+` group to avoid repeating the negative look-ahead so many times.

Alternatively, one could use a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), which essentially does the same thing (your regex engine might not support it):

```
/&#60;a href&#61;&#34;(?:[^&]+|(?!&#34;).)*+&#34;&#62;/s
```

As you can see it's *slightly* shorter.

Comment: That's what I was looking for - negative lookahead. Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

The initial regular expression that comes to mind is `/<a href=".*?">/`; a lazy expression (`.*?`) can be used to match the string between the quotes. However, as pointed out in the comments, because the regular expression is anchored by a >, it'll match the invalid tag as well, because a match is still made.

In order to get around this problem, you can use [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). Atomic grouping tells the regular expression engine, "once you have found a match for this group, accept it" -- this will solve the problem of the regex going back and matching the second string after not finding a > a the end of the href. The regular expression with an atomic group would look like:

```
/<a (?>href=".*?")>/
```

Which would look like the following when replacing the characters with their HTML entities:

```
/&#60;a (?>href&#61;&#34;.*?&#34;)&#62;/
```

Comment: But correct me if I'm wrong: when you use the .* even if you make it non-greedy with .*?, it will capture everything up until the last quote in the onmouseover attribute, matching both of the expressions. This is exactly the problem I am having!

Comment: You're right; because of the `>` at the end of the expression, the regular expression engine will match the invalid statement, because there is a match from the first quote to the end of the string. The solution here would be to use an atomic group, I will update my answer to explain.

Comment: Ah yeah, using the atomic group is a great idea (I usually make use of possessive quantifiers; essentially the same thing)! I added it to my regex, because otherwise it would do a lot of unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: Thanks guys. Great answers. I have no idea which one of these to mark as answered now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey! I had to do a similar thing recently. I recommend decoding the html first then attempt to grab the info you want. Here's my solution in C#:

```
private string getAnchor(string data)
    {
        MatchCollection matches;
        string pattern = @"<a.*?href=[""'](?<href>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        string anchor = "";

        matches = myRegex.Matches(data);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            anchor += match.Groups["href"].Value.Trim() + "," + match.Groups["text"].Value.Trim();
        }

        return anchor;
    }
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I upvoted this as this was going to be my 2nd solution but I'd prefer not to have to encode/decode and possibly re-encode the HTML if it has those extra attributes. Thanks for the help!